# carrierwave, Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently in RegistrationsController#update error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, carrierwave

ive been trying to get carrierwave to work with amazon s3. instead of

```
storage :s3
```

i have

```
storage :fog
```

changing it to storage :s3 gives an immediate error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629827/carrierwave-cant-convert-nil-into-string-typeerror-when-using-s3

so i changed it to storage :fog like the rdoc below says.

http://rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/frames

however when i try to upload an image, i get this crazy error. im using the devise gem as well.

my full stack trace is

```
Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently in RegistrationsController#update

Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently (Expected(200) <=> Actual(301 Moved Permanently)
  request => {:connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"Content-Length"=>95472, "Content-Type"=>"image/jpeg", "x-amz-acl"=>"private", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=315576000", "Date"=>"Thu, 17 May 2012 05:28:55 +0000", "Authorization"=>"AWS AKIAIN6SC3YSGBSUKV4Q:kZOG9mG01jYn48ImFMYbgxAAQRk=", "Host"=>"user.a.777.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443"}, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :mock=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_ca_file=>"/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/excon-0.13.4/data/cacert.pem", :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"user.a.777.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", :path=>"/uploads%2Fuser%2Fimage%2F59%2Fidea.jpg", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :body=>#<File:/Users/sasha/Desktop/rails_projects/blue_eyes/public/uploads/tmp/20120516-2228-19160-9893/idea.jpg>, :expects=>200, :idempotent=>true, :method=>"PUT"}
  response => #<Excon::Response:0x007fd72a146820 @body="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><RequestId>F5F5AF888E837622</RequestId><Bucket>user.a.777</Bucket><HostId>IShK3GIthzCQysLOKXnR+ijJiHmMuUtXBOpFxQM4uCvJgkEHfmFn43LL4oWmpT82</HostId><Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint></Error>", @headers={"x-amz-request-id"=>"F5F5AF888E837622", "x-amz-id-2"=>"IShK3GIthzCQysLOKXnR+ijJiHmMuUtXBOpFxQM4uCvJgkEHfmFn43LL4oWmpT82", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Thu, 17 May 2012 05:29:00 GMT", "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, @status=301>):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:30:in `update'
```

i dont know what that even means.

in my initializers/carrierwave.rb i have..

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'somekey',       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'secretkey',       # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1'  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket.name'                     # required
  #config.fog_host       = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'            # optional, defaults to nil
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

and my uploader file has

```
  #storage :s3
  storage :fog
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

my gem file has

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'thin'
gem 'fog'
```

when i boot my server, instead of webrick, it uses thin in development as well.

are my configurations wrong?
help would be much appreciated!
ive been super stuck on this carrierwave/s3 issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into this the earlier today and it was a problem with the region. Just take it out and let it be set by the default.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'somekey',       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'secretkey'       # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket.name'                     # required
  #config.fog_host       = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'       # optional, defaults to nil
  config.fog_public     = false                             # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'} # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For me worked this configuration

```
config.fog_directory  = 'bucket_name'                   
config.fog_host       = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket_name'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Following the 3 steps below worked for me.

1.Change the default region when creating a bucket

2.Edit my `carrierwave.rb` file(as shown below)

`initializers/carrierwave.rb`:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region => ENV['S3_REGION']
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

3.Configure heroku in the command line as in: `heroku config:set S3_REGION='your region'`

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Jason Bynum said, do not specify the region and let it default.

If you still fail, don't worry, At this time, heroku will give hint to you like `your region specified is wrong and should be xxx`

And you know how to fill the region right now :)

The followings work for me:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',                        # required
      aws_access_key_id:     ENV['S3_KEY'],                        # required
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'],                        # required
      region:                'ap-southeast-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'

  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'your_bucket_name'                          # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                        # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave', '0.10.0'
gem 'fog', '1.36.0'
```