# 301 Moved Permanently after S3 uploading

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, fog

Im trying to upload images to S3 on Ruby on Rails using carrierwave and fog gems, images are uploaded correctly but when I try tu save the model containing information about the image that was just uploaded Im getting this error:

```
Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently in UserController#show
app/models/user.rb:46:in `process_image_with_key'
app/controllers/user_controller.rb:12:in `show'

<Excon::Response:0x007f97846a3c18 @body="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message>
```

User model:

```
mount_uploader :image, AvatarUploader

def image_name
  File.basename(image.path || image.filename) if image
end

def process_image_with_key( key )
  unless key.nil?
    self.key = key
    self.remote_image_url = self.image.direct_fog_url(with_path: true)
    self.save!
  end
end
```

AvatarUploader:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [50, 50]
  end

end
```

User controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @user.process_image_with_key(params[:key])
  @uploader = User.new.image
  @uploader.success_action_redirect = user_url(@user.id)
end
```

carriwerwave initializer

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region                 => 'us-west-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_FILE_BUCKET']
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

gemfile

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```xml
<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access
must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to 
this endpoint.</Message></Error>
```

This is a frequently encountered issue: You are trying to access a bucket in region *us-west-1*, however, for legacy reasons the default [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) region in most/all [AWS SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/code) is *US Standard*, which *automatically routes requests to facilities in Northern Virginia or the Pacific Northwest using network maps* (see [Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) for details).

Therefore you simply need to specify the endpoint of your buckets region explicitly before using the S3 API, e.g. for *us-west-1*:

```ruby
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region                 => 'us-west-1'
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/'
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But some consideration I haven't made, and I will be explained below...

Comment: By the way, I'm having a weird validation message on uploading remote image from facebook/twitter users, I don't know if you have a couple of minutes to watch it [StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730976/image-invalid-on-facebook-twitter-user-image-uploading-to-s3)

Comment: This led me to the answer - funny thing though - the region in the url of my bucket in the aws console was different from the region listed under properties - so word the wise - double check that. It solved this issue for moi.

Comment: For me, this simplest answer worked as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630430/carrierwave-exconerrorsmovedpermanently-in-registrationscontrollerupdate-e

Comment: +1 @Jackson_Sandland, I had the exact same case – really dazzling because for S3 the console's Regions dropdown menu says they don't matter... but then they do for uploads!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to [Steffen Opel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45773/steffen-opel)!

But some consideration I haven't made, my region is US Standard, therefore, my carrierwave initializer looks like this:
    # :region => # NOT NEEDED BY US STANDARD
    :endpoint => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'

This [link](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) was the key :D