# Spring Batch with Spring Cloud AWS S3 returns 301 for EU bucket

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud

I'm attempting to read a file in Spring Batch that is hosted on S3.  I want to access the file directly from S3, not download it as a local file and then read.

Here's my reader:

```
class MyReader extends FlatFileItemReader<MyReadItem> {

    @Value('${com.me.s3bucket}')
    private String s3bucket;

    MyReader (DefaultLineMapper< MyReadItem > myLineMapper, ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.linesToSkip = 1
        this.lineMapper = myLineMapper
        this.resource = resourceLoader.getResource("s3://${s3bucket}/path/to/myfile.csv")
    }
}
```

The reader is wired up in my batch config file:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader< MyReadItem > reader() {
    return new MyReader(myLineMapper(), resourceLoader)
}

@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader

// myLineMapper ...
```

When I run the batch job, I get a 301 exception:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Moved Permanently (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: 1DAB29F45F62E0D9)
```

S3 301 exceptions appear to be because the region isn't defined when the request is made ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691881/301-moved-permanently-after-s3-uploading)), but my `application.yaml` file is shown below where I define the region:

```
cloud:
    aws:
        region:
            static: eu-west-1
            auto: false
```

What's going on here?  Is the problem something to do with the order the beans are wired up, perhaps before the configuration file is read?

To test, I have used this method to download S3 as a temp file within the same application and it works ok:

```
@Value('${com.me.s3bucket}')
private String s3bucket;

public static final String PREFIX = "s3temp";
public static final String SUFFIX = ".tmp";

public File downloadS3File(String resourcePath) throws IOException {
    Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource("s3://${s3bucket}/${resourcePath}");

    InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();

    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, SUFFIX);
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out);
    }
    finally {
    }

    return tempFile;
}
```

Is there any way of explicitly specifying the region when using resource loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the problem was with the fact that the bucket wasn't being set and was null.

```
@Value('${com.me.s3bucket}')
private String s3bucket;
```

I don't know why this was, but when I moved this out of the class and sent the value as a job parameter, it worked.