# CORS. Presigned URL. S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I've generated a presigned S3 POST URL. Using the return parameters, I then pass it into my code, but I keep getting this error `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`.

Whereas on Postman, I'm able to submit the form-data with one attached file.

On PostMan, I manually entered the parameters
[image]

The same parameters are then entered into my code.
[image]

Comment: The difference between what the browser is doing and Postman is that Postman is only doing the POST method. The browser is doing "preflight" which means that is does an OPTIONS request before the POST. It uses the CORS headers from the OPTIONS response to see if it should continue to do the POST. You can check what the OPTIONS response looks like in Postman.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You must edit the **CORS Configuration** to be public , something like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

[image]

Comment: doesn't make sense, because I was able to upload via Postman. This is a POST request. Not a GET

Comment: Sorry, I mean CORS Configuration.. I updated the answer. Sorry again!

Comment: Thank you for the tip. "Allowed Header: *" helped a little and I am getting some headway. What perplexed me is that the same thing worked in PostMan. But not on my code

Comment: @ngzhongcai fwiw, this works in postman and other test tools because postman is not a web site.  CORS is a browser mechanism that prevents site A from making requests to site B (that's your bucket) unless site B agrees to accept the request from a viewer of site A via a "preflight check."  The browser requires a CORS-friendly response when you're using one web site to access another but postman would not need/use/trigger this safety mechanism, because it's actually designed to protect both the user and site B from potentially malicious code on site A, and there is no site A under postman.

Comment: Thank you Michael!

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I have also faced the same issue, i could fix it by making allowedHeader to * . But I did not understand why we need to make it * and not any specific header as mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonRequestHeaders.html

Comment: This didn't work with AllowHeader * , did anyone fix this  ?

Comment: Where to add? 
in S3 console / yourBucket / Permissions / CORS configuration
and set 
<AllowedOrigin>h t t p s : //yourdomain.cloud</AllowedOrigin>
in my case * was not enough...

Comment: It's funny how often people think postman proves there's no CORS error.

Comment: @doug65536 To be fair, we habitually think of security errors as something that must come from the server -- the client cannot be trusted. On top of that, the server does in fact set the CORS policy, so _of course_ it's a server-side concern, right? The idea that the server is setting a policy but the client's browser is enforcing it is extremely unintuitive. You have to sit down and think about the actual purpose of CORS (to protect the client against a malicious third party) to understand why it is the way it is.

Answer (score 50):

Unable to comment so adding this here. Contains Harvey's answer, but in the form of a text to make it easy to copy.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 19):

On my case I fixed it by having allowedMethods, and origins in S3. The menu is under the Permissions tab

[image]

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it was text, not an image that others cannot easily copy from.

Comment: Hello, I am wondering in my case it doesn't work. I know CORS paramaters.
I allowed all origin like above settings. But still getting CORS 403 error as a response of PUT request.

Answer (score 15):

I encountered this issue as well. My CORs configuration on my bucket seemed correct yet my presigned URLs were hitting CORs problems. It turns out my `AWS_REGION` for my presigner was not set to the aws region of the bucket. After setting `AWS_REGION` to the correct region, it worked fine. I'm annoyed that the CORS issue was such a red herring to a simple problem and wasted several hours of my time.

Comment: How do you figure out correct region? "S3 does not require region selection." Their region is "Global"

Comment: Region can be found in properties tab of the bucket.

Comment: wow, thanks. been struggling with this for ages!

Comment: @DmitryEfimenko Bucket region is part of the signed data in a presigned URL - see the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html).

Answer (score 3):

In my case I specifically needed to allow the PUT method in the S3 Bucket's CORS Configuration to use the presigned URL, not the GET method as in the accepted answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 2):

My issue was I had a trailing slash (/) at the end of the domain in "AllowedOrigins". Once I removed the slash, requests worked.

Comment: Wonderful, all CORS config was right in our setup, yet it was not working, finally removing the trailing / solved our problem

Answer (score 2):

I used boto3 to add the cors policy, and this is what worked for me. Used the logic by @Pranav Joglekar

```
cors_configuration = {
        'CORSRules': [{
            'AllowedHeaders': ['*'],
            'AllowedMethods': ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST'],
            'AllowedOrigins': ['*'],
            'ExposeHeaders': [],
            'MaxAgeSeconds': 3000
        }]
    }
    s3_client = get_s3_client()
    s3_client.put_bucket_cors(Bucket='my_bucket_name',
                       CORSConfiguration=cors_configuration)
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that for some reason - `getSignedUrl` returned a url like so:

> https://my-bucket.s3.**us-west-2**.amazonaws.com/bucket-folder/file.jpg

I've removed the region part - `us-west-2` - and that fixed it ‍♂️

So instead it is now

> https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-folder/file.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar CORS errors even with things properly configured.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703595/11832970), I discovered my Lambda@Edge that presigns was using a region that wasn't the right one for this bucket. (which was on us-east-1 for some default stack reason).

So I had to be explicit about the region when generating the presignedPost

reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703595/11832970

Comment: It took me 1 whole day before getting this right. The CORS error was only confusing, and I should have focused on the 301 status

Answer (score 0):

For me,it was because my bucket name had a hyphen in it (e.g. **my-bucket**). The signed URL would replace the hyphen in the bucket name with an underscore and then sign it. So this meant two things:

1. CORS wouldn't work because the URL technically wasn't correct
2. I couldn't just change the underscore back to the hyphen because then the signature would be wrong when AWS validated the signed URL

I eventually had to rename my bucket to something without a hyphen (e.g. **mybucket**) and then it worked fine with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the url encoding.  I had a url encoded version of the pre-resigned URL and that failed until I decoded it.

Answer (score 0):

in my case URl was written as https=/www.xxx-qa.com. I changed it to https://www.xxx-qa.com and issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I had a bucket with dots (`.`) in name, like: `cdn.dev.company.com` (which was used with Cloudflare (not AWS Cloudfront) as CDN for serving media files). Below is python code snippet which was used by backend to generate preseigned URLs (that were used by frontend to upload video files directly to S3 bucket). Check the comment next to "client" variable line. In that configuration, it worked well (you also need to add CORS policy in bucket details - which is already described in this thread).

```py
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
from django.conf import settings

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name=settings.AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
)

# you need to define endpoint_url and addressing_style as virtual in order 
# to generate URLs that are friendly for web-browser and work well with CORS
client = session.client(
    "s3",
    endpoint_url=f"https://s3.{settings.AWS_S3_REGION_NAME}.amazonaws.com",
    config=Config(s3={"addressing_style": "virtual"}),
)

bucket = settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
key = "file.png"
upload_id = "zxcv"
part_number = "abcd"
default_url_expiration = 1200

client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod="upload_part",
    Params={
        "Bucket": bucket,
        "Key": key,
        "UploadId": upload_id,
        "PartNumber": part_number,
    },
    ExpiresIn=default_url_expiration,
    HttpMethod="PUT",
)
```

Comment: I had the same issue as @michal-mchalak, however, their solution did not work for me. I was generating a url `generate_presigned_url` on the backend to allow a web app to add files. However, I kept getting a CORs issue when the web app tried a file with a `.` in it. E.g., `/my_file.csv`.

My solution was to use `generated_presigned_post`, as this moves the path to the body. See https://zaccharles.medium.com/s3-uploads-proxies-vs-presigned-urls-vs-presigned-posts-9661e2b37932 or https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/generate_presigned_post.html

Answer (score -1):

We have to specify only the required HTTP method. we were using the POST method for Presigned URL so removed the "GET" and "PUT" methods from "AllowedMethods"

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```