# Tensorflow - S3 object does not exist

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3

**How do I set up direct private bucket access for Tensorflow?**

After running
`from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io`
and running print `file_io.stat('s3://my/private/bucket/file.json')` I end up with an error -
`NotFoundError: Object s3://my/private/bucket/file.json does not exist`

However, the same line on a public object works without an error:
`print file_io.stat('s3://ryft-public-sample-data/wikipedia-20150518.bin')`

There appears to be an article on support here: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/docs/deploy/s3.md
However, I end up with the same error after exporting the variables shown.

I have awscli set up with all credentials, and boto3 can view and download the file in question. I am wondering how I can get Tensorflow to have S3 access directly when the bucket is private.

Comment: Is TensorFlow using the same AWS credentials as that used by `boto` to view and download the file in question? Was the file created by a different profile than that Tensorflow is using?

Comment: Tensorflow is supposed to be using the ~/.aws/credentials file as stated in the linked support article, which is the profile that has full access to the bucket and created the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to access files in private S3 bucket from Sagemaker notebook. The mistake I made was to try using credentials I obtained from boto3, which seem not to be valid outside.

The solution was not to specify credentials (in such case it uses the role attached to the machine), but instead just specify the region name (for some reason it didn't read it from `~/.aws/config` file) as follows:

```
import boto3
import os

session = boto3.Session()
os.environ['AWS_REGION']=session.region_name
```

NOTE: when debugging this error useful was to look at CloudWatch logs, as the logs of S3 client were printed only there and not in the Jupyter notebook.
In there I have first have seen, that:

1. when I did specify credentials from boto3 the error was: `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`
2. When accessing without `AWS_REGION` env variable set I had `The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.` which apparently is common when you don't specify bucket (see [301 Moved Permanently after S3 uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691881/301-moved-permanently-after-s3-uploading))